# Load Page to ID on Subsequent Pages of Pagination of Custom Loop

Tags: loops, pagination

I have a page with top half content of static text and bottom half of a custom loop with pagination.

How can I target the subsequent pages of the pagination so on page load they load to the anchor ID of the container of the custom loop (keeping the initial page loading normally)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer is paginate_links() - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links#Examples

I changed the value for `add_fragment` by adding on my ID and including that code in the template file and works ok - my anchor link being **#pr1**

```
            echo paginate_links( array(
                'base'                 => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big, false ) ),
                //'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
                'current'              => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total'                => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                'type'                 => 'list',
                'add_fragment'         => '#pr1',
            ) );
```

This [helped](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195283/adding-anchor-to-paginate-links-safari-anchor-bug) a lot.